# Counting number of words of each column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, xsl-stylesheet

I'am trying to implement a code so that all the number of words from each cell in a column can be calculated and displayed in a cell just next to them.

I have written this code, but it shows Complie Error: Loop without Do, where as I'am having it.

```
Sub Command()
    total_words = 1
    Dim ans_length As Integer
    Dim start_point As Integer

    Range("N3").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

        ans_length = Len(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value)
        For start_point = 1 To ans_length
            If (Mid(ans_length, start_point, 1)) = " " Then
            total_words = total_words + 1
            End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = total_words
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

say i have this content:

```
      Col1                      Col2
The only way to do multi   |      6
line comments in VB        |      4
the only option you have   |      5
is the single              |      3
```

here i have col2 by default and writing VBA code for col2

Comment: You’re missing a NEXT for your FOR and I reckon you’d be better to write a UDD rather than the macro like that. It means it could be applied anywhere independent of the range.

Comment: This is one of the main reason why you should always indent your code :)  I have mentioned this problem [HERE - See point no 4](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2017/12/15/to-err-is-human/) as well

Comment: You can count the number of 'words' in a cell by counting the number of spaces and adding one. That can be done with a formula, you don't need VBA at all..

Comment: I agree with @CLR: But if you want to use VBA, just `Split` the text in an array and get the array count. That should be the word count. Also, consider looking at: **why we shouldn't use `Select` or `Activate` in VBA**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This UDF approach would be an easier option ... well ... in my opinion anyway.

```
Public Function CountWords(ByVal strText As String) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    CountWords = UBound(Split(strText, " ")) + 1
End Function
```

... you can then use that in any cell.

[image]

If you want to go with your original approach, you were missing a NEXT.

```
Sub Command()
    total_words = 1

    Dim ans_length As Integer
    Dim start_point As Integer

    Range("N3").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        ans_length = Len(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value)

        For start_point = 1 To ans_length
            If (Mid(ans_length, start_point, 1)) = " " Then
                total_words = total_words + 1
            End If
        Next start_point

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = total_words
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added the NEXT and the pointer is moving correctly cell to cell in a row but but getting inside the For loop and not setting value to (0,12) cell

Comment: Did you consider using my UDF?  It would be a better and more sustainable approach.  I strongly suggest it.

Comment: Actually I need to work on VBA that's why, else would have tried that...

Comment: @MrE the function is VBA though.  Anyway, check your MID statement.  It's not correct.  Mid works like ... Mid("This is the text", 4, 1) ... that will give you "s" ... you're passing in 2 integers.  Check the documentation on it.  Something like this ... If Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value, start_point, 1) = " " Then

Comment: @MrE ... be careful with what you're doing.  You have changed your original question.  I answered your original question and now you have changed it and unflagged my answer.  My answer should stand as correct.  You need to be clearer in relation to what you're trying to achieve if you want help with the business logic.  Your syntax error was answered and answered correctly.

Comment: How can I convert the UDF to take whole selected column and show output in column form only